# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v7:20.0.+

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new for android development
I had write

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
>
> runproduard() is replaced with minifyenabled. The result : Build successful

but at the run time this error occures:

My code is:

> `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'`

but 698 warnings as can't find referenced class xom which is added in libs folder

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardMobifoodDemoDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

My android studio version is 1.0.2 and gradle version is 2.2.1

Comment: What is xom? Is it a another library?

Comment: xstream147.jar file which is added in libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build.gradle in the module directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
}
```

The "+" allows gradle to auto upgrade to latest bug fix version of the jar.

build.gradle in the outermost project directory

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

local.properties

```
sdk.dir=/Tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk
```

Comment: same error : Unexpected Error
            Local path doesn't exist.
Local path doesn't exist.
The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
            Sync Project with Gradle files

Comment: You have to ensure the right combination of gradle version and tools are used. Ensure Android Studio is latest with all SDK's updated.

Comment: Thank you so much.I had tried this in my app....but still error is: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardAppNameDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first....plz help me..

Comment: You need to post more information on the exception. Is this a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Change `com.android.support:support-v7:20.0.+` in your apps build.gradle to

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
```

Comment: This is not working..Unexpected Error
            Local path doesn't exist.
Local path doesn't exist.
The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
            Sync Project with Gradle files

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}
is this the same format you added in app build.gradle

Comment: Try this steps:
right click your jar > add as library

Comment: There is not any option like add as lib ...I think It is already added therefore it doesn't shown